# Build driver plugin QIBASE Qt 4.7.3

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, firebird

I try to build QIBASE driver in Qt 4.7.3

ibase.pro

```
TARGET = qsqlibase

SOURCES = main.cpp

INCLUDEPATH += "C:/Program Files/Firebird/Firebird_2_0/include" "C:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.7.3/mingw/lib"

LIBS += -L"C:/Program Files/Firebird/Firebird_2_0/lib/fbclient_ms.lib" -L"C:/Program Files/Firebird/Firebird_2_0/lib/fbclient_bor.lib"

include(../../../sql/drivers/ibase/qsql_ibase.pri)

include(../qsqldriverbase.pri)
```

sql\drivers\ibase\qsql_ibase.pri

```
HEADERS += $$PWD/qsql_ibase.h
SOURCES += $$PWD/qsql_ibase.cpp

unix {
    !contains(LIBS, .*gds.*):!contains(LIBS, .*libfb.*):LIBS += -lgds
} else {
    !contains(LIBS, .*gds.*):!contains(LIBS, .*fbclient.*) {
        win32-borland:LIBS += fbclient_bor.lib
        else:LIBS += -lfbclient_ms
    }
}
```

Output:

```
C:\QtSDK\src\src\plugins\sqldrivers\ibase>qmake

C:\QtSDK\src\src\plugins\sqldrivers\ibase>make
make -f Makefile.Debug all
make[1]: Entering directory `C:/QtSDK/src/src/plugins/sqldrivers/ibase'
g++ -enable-stdcall-fixup -Wl,-enable-auto-import -Wl,-enable-runtime-pseudo-rel
oc -mthreads -Wl -shared -Wl,--out-implib,c:/QtSDK/src/plugins/sqldrivers/libqsq
libased4.a -o ../../../../plugins/sqldrivers/qsqlibased4.dll tmp/obj/debug_share
d/main.o tmp/obj/debug_shared/qsql_ibase.o tmp/obj/debug_shared/moc_qsql_ibase.o
  -L'c:/QtSDK/src/lib' -L'c:/QtSDK/src/lib' tmp/obj/debug_shared/qsqlibased_reso
urce_res.o "-LC:/Program Files/Firebird/Firebird_2_0/lib/fbclient_ms.lib" "-LC:/
Program Files/Firebird/Firebird_2_0/lib/fbclient_bor.lib" -lQtSqld4 -lQtCored4
c:/qtsdk/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cann
ot find -lQtSqld4
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [../../../../plugins/sqldrivers/qsqlibased4.dll] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `C:/QtSDK/src/src/plugins/sqldrivers/ibase'
make: *** [debug-all] Error 2
```

ld.exe: cannot find **-lQtSqld4**

in C:\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.7.3\mingw\lib libQtSqld4.a exist

before that I was an error "C:\QtSDK\src\bin moc.exe not found" and i copied moc.exe into "C:\QtSDK\src\bin."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is solved by the advice of colleagues

Need to change the file ibase.pro only and specify the path to header files in the source directory not in directory of the SDK

ibase.pro

```
TARGET = qsqlibase

SOURCES = main.cpp
INCLUDEPATH += "C:/Program Files/Firebird/Firebird_2_0/include" C:/tmp/src/include
LIBS += "C:/Program Files/Firebird/Firebird_2_0/lib/fbclient_ms.lib"

include(../../../sql/drivers/ibase/qsql_ibase.pri)

include(../qsqldriverbase.pri)
```