# How to connect Firebird DB with Qt?

Tags: qt, firebird

I am really new to Firebird and I want to implement really really easy task in order to understand how I can work with it. Can you please give me a link or a piece of code with a little information about how I can reach Firebird using Qt ?

Thank you very much for you all

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Qt toolkit contains many great SQL drivers and among them is also an FireBird SQL driver.
http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/sql-driver.html#qibase-for-borland-interbase

To use it on windows/linux you need to recompile the driver 
Here is one example with Firebird embedded :
. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/47457/Get-Started-with-QT-and-Embedded-FireBird

Also you can recompile it with mingw compiler that comes with Qt :
[Build driver plugin QIBASE Qt 4.7.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6516402/build-driver-plugin-qibase-qt-4-7-3)